# WPF Textblock doesn't render Unicode

Tags: c#, wpf, unicode

When i set text at design time
`<TextBlock Text="&#x2022;ABC (2343)&#13;&#x2022;XYZ (324)&#13;"></TextBlock>`

it works show bullet circle

but when i assign same text at runtime (programmatically) it doesn't render as it should instead show text as string literal.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to XAML being XML which means the encoded characters will be converted when it’s being read through the XML parser. This isn’t a feature of `TextBlock`.

If you want to have characters like that you need to encode them accordingly. In C# a string literal can have Unicode escaped into it:

```
var s = “\u2022ABC (2343)\u000d\u2022XYZ (324)\u000d”;
```

Note that the values must be four characters long always.

And instead of `\u000d` you can use `\r`